# why $x^3=11^3$ mod $5083$ has only one solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Why $x^3=11^3$ mod $5083$ has only one solution? (The only answer is $x=11$)

I know it has at most 3 roots but how to find that there isn't another answer?

Comment: Observation $5083=13\cdot 17\cdot 23$

Comment: $x=11$ is not the only solution, try $x = 3530$ or $x = 3921$.

Answer (score 2):

As $5083=13\cdot 17\cdot 23$

We have $\displaystyle\left(\frac x{11}\right)^3\equiv1\pmod{13}\ \ \ \ (1)$

As all primes  have primitive roots, taking discrete logarithm wrt some primitive root $g$ of $13,$(say $2$)

$3$ind$\displaystyle_g \left(\frac x{11}\right)\equiv0\pmod {12}\ \ \ \ (2)$

Using Linear Congruence [Theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence),  $(2)$ hence $(1)$ have $(3,12)=3$ solutions namely, $4k\pmod{13}$ where $k=0,1,2$ of $(2)$

$\implies 2^{4k}\pmod{13},k=0,1,2$ of $(1)$

Similarly,   $\displaystyle\left(\frac x{11}\right)^3\equiv1\pmod{17}$ and $\displaystyle\left(\frac x{11}\right)^3\equiv1\pmod{23}$ should have unqiue solutions namely $1$

Using [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html),  we shall get three in-congruent solutions $\pmod{13\cdot 17\cdot 23}$

Comment: thanks. Is there any way besides discrete logarithm to solve this?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi, if we write $x=11y,$ we need each prime factor$(p)$ of $5083$ to divide $(y^3-1)=(y-1)(y^2+y+1)$

$\implies y\equiv1\pmod p$ is a solution

Else $y^2+y+1\equiv0\pmod p\iff (2y+1)^2\equiv-3\pmod p$

$\implies -3$ is a Quadrtaic Residue of $p$

Now, using Quadratic Reciprocity or otherwise we can prove that $-3$ is a Quadratic Residue of $p$ iff $p\equiv1\pmod6$ which only $13$ qualifies. So, $17,23$ will have only one solutions i.e., $y\equiv1$

Comment: I guess you could just try all $x$ modulo 13, 17 and 23.

Comment: @apt1002, we can substaitially minimize computation using the method mentioned in my last comment

Comment: Indeed. My method instead minimises the required background reading. ;-)

Comment: How to find how many roots it has?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi, $(x/11)^3\equiv1\pmod{13}$ has three, namely $1,2^4\equiv3,2^8\equiv3^2\equiv9\pmod{13}$ $(x/11)^3\equiv1\pmod{17}$ and $(x/11)^3\equiv1\pmod{23}$ have one each, namely $1$.  Now apply CRT